# Add current date using inline javascript

Tags: javascript, date

The date is not showing up in the output when I run the following code.  I can't seem to figure out why the date won't show up...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>document.write() Example</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p>The current date and time is:
 <script type=”text/javascript”>
 document.write(“<strong>” + (new Date()).toString() + “</strong>”);
 </script>
 </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you are using these types of quotes: `“ ... ”`. You need to use `" ... "`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<strong>" + (new Date()).toString() + "</strong>");
</script>
```

**Snippet:**

```js
 document.write("<strong>" + (new Date()).toString() + "</strong>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it as the way the samurais do it...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p>The current date and time is: <span id="myDate"></span> </p>

    <script>

      var d = new Date;
      var date = d.toString();

      span = document.getElementById('myDate');
      txt = document.createTextNode(date);
      span.innerText = txt.textContent;

    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Google chrome stopped  accepting document.write due to security issues. This should be the right answer now.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this snippet. It is similar to what you used but avoid using document.write.

Plus is safer because it cannot overwrite all the document if it was loaded.

```html
<p id="date"></p>

<script>
date = document.getElementById("date");
date.innerHTML = new Date();
</script>
```

Comment: As long as the DOM is still in the process of loading there is no problem with using `document.write`. There is nothing wrong in this case for the OP's code. Not to say there is any harm in pointing out problems with `document.write`

Comment: You are right i edited my answer, but anyway is a better practice avoid using document.write whenever is possible. For example, you don't have Javascript and HTML in the same place, this doing a more maintainable code.

Comment: I agree with you, in most cases `document.write` needs to be avoided, functions should be separate from structure, etc. Defiantly for beginner programmers who may not know that it can overwrite the DOM. But it haves its places. In case your wondering I didn't down-vote you.