# "info" element is not being updated with ".innerHTML" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Firstly, this is homework but I have done everything within my knowledge to try to fix this.

I just don't see why this bit of javascript code does not seem to work when I test run the index.html file (code attached) and tried to open it in web browser. I have definitely checked multiple times that the js file is in fact named "calendar.js" and I have also tried to change the file name in both the html and js.

Oddly enough, it works just fine in the stack overflow test.

```js
function updatePage()
{
  var d = new Date();
  var e = document.getElementById("info");
  e.innerHTML = "Time is now " + d;
}

function startUpdate()
{
  updatePage();
  window.setInterval(updatePage, 10 * 1000);
}
window.onload = startUpdate;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="calendar.js" type=“text/javascript”></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="info"></h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>8:30-9:30</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>9:30-10:30</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>10:30-11:30</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>11:30-12:30</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>12:30-1:30</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>1:30-2:30</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2:30-3:30</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>3:30-4:30</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>4:30-5:30</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>5:30-6:30</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>6:30-7:30</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>7:30-8:30</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>8:30-9:30</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>9:30-10:30</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *You probably are not correctly linking to the JavaScript file. One problem appears to be the quotes you are using in the `<script>` tag being `type=“text/javascript”`, it should be `type="text/javascript"`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek wow that worked, how did you spot that...Thanks!

Comment: I happen to of answered this [type of question before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368682/add-current-date-using-inline-javascript) :)

Comment: *Note:* Since that solved the issue this question can be marked as the duplicate of the [one linked above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368682/add-current-date-using-inline-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Moving your  tag to just before the end of the body tag like so may do the trick:

```
    ...
    </table>
    <script src="calendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The reason is explained in [this link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/adding-interactivity-with-javascript#parser-blocking-vs-asynchronous-javascript)

Comment: It's in a `window.onload` event, it doesn't need to be at the end of the body.

Comment: I see your point because window.onload fires after all is set. However, placing script tag in head curiously yielded 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null' error. I am trying to envision the scenario when the script tag is placed in head tag: the parser pauses for the script to be fetched and then executed, then it sees window.onload -wouldn't it stall at this point?